# Correct placement of error handling/logging in bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to add a few additional checks to an sftp transfer script (this reads from a csv to pull in names (col1)/ids (col2) -- this part works fine). Actually the script works fine - but as I am to do this on a daily basis I need to append the logfile with a date - so when it writes to /root/logs/daily_transfer.log it doesn't overwrite the previous day - also -- if the transfer fails -- to include a sendmail feature to alert of the failed transfer.

I have tried adding `date '+%d-%b-%Y %T'` suffix to daily_transfer.log ie.
exec  >  /root/logs/logfile.logdaily_transfer.log
but this fails with:
line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'

My script current working script (albeit without date suffix to log & sendmail is:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec  >  /root/logs/logfile.log`date '+%d-%b-%Y %T'`

set -x
while IFS="," read -r col1 col2
do
        echo "user: $col1"
        echo "id: $col2"

        cd /efs/$col1/ftpout
        cp * /efs/$col1/backup
        sftp -oIdentityfile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa user@site.domain.com:/home/folder <<EOF
                put *.txt
                exit
EOF
rm *.txt

        done < <(tail -n +2 us_craig.csv)
```

Comment: Where is the code that includes the date logic causing the error?

Comment: Ive edited the code to show where it was placed -- without the `date '+%d-%b-%Y %T'` the script works but obviously doesn't have the timestamp.

Comment: We don't do design advice here -- our scope is limited to narrow, specific questions with testably correct answers (as opposed to matters of "best practice" or opinion). Can you try to make the question more specific?

Comment: For example, "how do I prevent a redirection from overwriting a preexisting file?" is a concrete question with demonstrably correct answers.

Comment: Some of your problems, btw, would be solved by better quoting. `exec >"/root/logs/logfile.log.$(date +%Y-%m-%d %T)"` -- **note the quotes; they're important**. Likewise the use of `$()` instead of backticks; these have been mandated by the POSIX sh standard since the early 1990s (so they're completely portable to all modern shells), and have far better nesting behavior.

Comment: Consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Comment: Also, do seriously consider standardizing on `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S` for dates inside filenames -- that way the filename's sort order is the same as the date sort order. Also, while fixing your quoting is the Right Thing, choosing a date format without a space in it would have been an alternate way to work around your immediate bug.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:
`echo -e "whatever you want to say" | sed -e "s/^/$(date "+%d-%b-%Y %T") /" >> /root/logs/logfile.log`